# Shell Script error: "head: invalid trailing option -- 1"

Tags: linux, bash

I have this code in my shell(bash) script for splitting a file into smaller parts:

```
for (( i=$start; i<=$lineCount; i=i+$interval))
do
    temp=`expr $i + $interval`;
    if [ $temp -le $lineCount ]
    then
        command="head -$temp $fileName | tail -$interval > $tmpFileName";
        echo "Creating Temp File: $command";
    else
        lastLines=`expr $lineCount - $i`;
        command="head -$temp $fileName | tail -$lastLines > tmpFileName";
        echo "Creating Temp File: $command";
    fi
    `$command`;
done
```

It prints the following output on stdin:

```
Creating Temp File: head -10 tmp.txt | tail -10 > tmp.txt_TMP
head: invalid trailing option -- 1
Try `head --help' for more information.
```

But the command printed: `head -10 tmp.txt | tail -10 > tmp.txt_TMP` runs correctly on the command line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to use the `split` command..

Comment: split -l 10 /etc/passwd  passwd   wc -l passwda*
  10 passwdaa
  10 passwdab
  10 passwdac
  10 passwdad
   9 passwdae
  49 total

Comment: thanks. I ended up using the `split` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the pipe `|` in a variable, the shell interprets it as an ordinary character and not as a pipe.  Ditto for redirection operators like `>`, `<`, ...

An ugly way would be to use `eval`.

A better approach would be to split your command into different parts so as to get rid of pipes and redirection operators in it.

For example:

```
command="head -$temp $fileName | tail -$lastLines > tmpFileName";
```

would be written as:

```
cmd1="head -$temp $fileName";
cmd2="tail -$lastLines";
```

and executed by saying:

```
"$cmd1" | "$cmd2" > tmpFileName;
```

---

Moreover, you don't need backticks to execute a command that is stored in a variable.  Simply say:

```
$command
```

Comment: This is going to fail if ``$fileName`` contains spaces. Check out this link: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko Thanks for enlightening.

Comment: Also I don't understand what are you doing in this code. ``cmd1="head -$temp $fileName | tail -$lastLines > tmpFileName";`` and then ``"$cmd1" | "$cmd2" > tmpFileName;`` so that would result in a ``head -$temp $fileName | tail -$lastLines > tmpFileName | tail -$lastLines``, right?

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the edit; didn't notice the copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
command="head -$temp $fileName | tail -$interval > $tmpFileName"
```

and later:

```
`$command`
```

Instead of storing whole piped command in a string you can directly execute the command:

```
head -$temp "$fileName" | tail -$interval > "$tmpFileName"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here. First of all, lets see our refactored version with correct quoting and many other improvements:

```
for (( i=start; i<=lineCount; i+=interval)); do
    ((temp = i + interval))
    if (( temp <= lineCount )); then
        echo "Creating Temp File using 'tail -n $interval'"
        head -n "$temp" "$fileName" | tail -n "$interval" > "$tmpFileName"
    else
        ((lastLines = lineCount - i))
        echo "Creating Temp File using 'tail -n $lastLines'"
        head -n "$temp" "$fileName" | tail -n "$lastLines" > "$tmpFileName"
    fi
done
```

I have changed all arithmetic expressions to [correct syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr). This is what you want, because it is more readable.
Then, it seems like you want to put a command into a variable and then run it. To cut the story short, you simply should not do that. [Here's why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
Also, this is not c++, you don't have to place `;` on every line.
You have also missed `$` character in `tmpFileName` on the 10th line of your code.